# TestCafe Element is Visible but cannot be clicked

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, google-chrome-headless, ui-testing

I'm running TestCafe in an Alpine docker image using Chromium 68 headless to test a React application. I'm able to get other tests working, but for some reason, I have an issue where an element appears to be visible but cannot be clicked.

```
.expect(Selector('.ui.text.vertical.marketplace-side-nav.menu').find('a').withText('Pending').visible).ok()
.click(Selector('.ui.text.vertical.marketplace-side-nav.menu').find('a').withText('Pending'))
```

The first line passes, but the second line gives the following error:

`1) The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.`

I've tried setting up the test on TestCafe Studio and tried multiple selectors. I've set `.resizeWindow(2000, 1000)` at the beginning to ensure it's not an issue with responsive UX.

**Edit**

The [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/b38cc30d8c31edc30c1e6306c93b53b6) has a bit of other dev stuff, but is fairly straight-forward.

The project itself is proprietary so I can't share the code here.

Comment: Your test scenario looks valid. Could you please provide the Docker image or the Dockerfile with your project so that we can reproduce this problem?

Comment: So, it was an issue with resize, I added code to temporarily remove the navigation hide on smaller screens and it worked. Unfortunately I'm getting `Cannot read property 'Emulation' of undefined` when I try to use `resizeWindow` on headless so looking into that.

Comment: Final result if anyone else is stuck: Older version of Alpine Docker image was installing Chromium 57 (I had v68 elsewhere and ran the build to confirm). Upgrading Alpine and Chromium (now at 61+) fixed a lot of issues, and now emulation (and in turn resize) works as well.

Comment: @Fluidbyte, thank you for sharing your findings with everyone. Since you've found what's going on, I recommend that you post your comment as an answer to your own question, so people will refer to it if they face a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per the author's comment:

*Final result if anyone else is stuck: Older version of Alpine Docker image was installing Chromium 57 (I had v68 elsewhere and ran the build to confirm). Upgrading Alpine and Chromium (now at 61+) fixed a lot of issues, and now emulation (and in turn resize) works as well.*